# Open the original app after handling a URL to launch a second app on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an URL in a first app (Notes for example), when I click on the URL I catch an intent in MyApp and launch it.

So I push the home button on my phone to go to de desk, and click on Notes app but launch MyApp again.

I want to when I did click, start the Notes App, not MyApp.

This is my intent on MyApp MainActivity:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

   <data   android:scheme =    "https"
           android:host =      "formiik.com"
           android:pathPrefix ="/citas"/>
   <data   android:scheme  =   "http"
           android:host =      "www.formiik.com"
           android:pathPrefix ="/citas"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Do I need another intructions?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just add on your activity declaration the flag:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [clearTaskOnLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing) flag, then MyApp will always be separate from Notes app in the app list.